# How can I ajust this dataframe index?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nat

I have a dataframe which has a column with dates, and four readings per day like this:

```
Date       Readings         Values

2016-05-16 Reading 1         0.1
Nat        NaN (Reading 2)   0.1
Nat        Std               0
Nat        Mean              0.1
2016-05-17 ''                0.5
Nat
```

I wonder how I can create a `multiindex` that groups the 4 values under the same date and reading type, ignoring the NaT values.

Answer (score 0):

It seems need first forward fill values of `Date` column and then [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for `MultiIndex`:

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].ffill()

df = df.set_index(['Date', 'Readings'])
print (df)
                            Values
Date       Readings               
2016-05-16 Reading 1           0.1
           NaN (Reading 2)     0.1
           Std                 0.0
           Mean                0.1
2016-05-17 ''                  0.5
```

It working, because under the hood all `MultiIndex` values are repeated if duplicated:

```
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print (df)

                            Values
Date       Readings               
2016-05-16 Reading 1           0.1
2016-05-16 NaN (Reading 2)     0.1
2016-05-16 Std                 0.0
2016-05-16 Mean                0.1
2016-05-17 ''                  0.5
```